# Use two local ips in same port

Tags: java, java-8

Is it possible in local to use two local ips (`127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2`) apart from use `/etc/host` to create alias?

I'm trying to test two services that point to the same `port`.

I was trying to use `NettyServerBuilder` with `InetSocketAddress` in ip `127.0.0.2` but it's not possible and return a `Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`

```
final SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.2", 8888);

Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(socketAddress)
    .addService(coordinator)
    .build();
server.start();

final SocketAddress socketAddress2 = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8888);

Server server2 = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(socketAddress2)
    .addService(coordinator)
    .build();
server2.start();
```

Comment: Mask `8` is used on local machines, so your addresses are interpreted as the same https://superuser.com/a/393701/891550

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/508324/is-it-possible-to-run-two-services-on-the-same-ports-with-different-ip-but-on-th

Comment: Deploy them on separate Docker containers and map them to different host ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost,

> IPv4 network standards reserve the entire 127.0.0.0/8 address block for loopback purposes. That means any packet sent to one of those 16,777,214 addresses (127.0.0.1 through 127.255.255.254) is looped back. IPv6 has just a single address, ::1.

So you cannot use the same port number for two loopback addresses unless you change DNS resolution editing `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

Each port has a single, so if you have run your program it will throw an error, but if run two instances then use diffrent available port.

```
final SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.2", 8888);

Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(socketAddress)
    .addService(coordinator)
    .build();
server.start();

final SocketAddress socketAddress2 = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", [Available_Port]);

Server server2 = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(socketAddress2)
    .addService(coordinator)
    .build();
server2.start();
```

Comment: it's more complicated than that

Comment: Now see this, i hope you will understand

Comment: A 'port' is a port number on a protocol on an interface.  1.2.3.4:80 is a different port to 1.2.3.5:80.  The local interface may be a special case.

Comment: @Batek'S, it's valid what you wrote, but you're not answering the question.